# using promise fulfilled, rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function task1(fullfill, reject) {
console.log('Task1 start');
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Task1 end');
    //fullfill('Task1 result');
    reject('Error msg');
}, 300);
}
function fullfilled(result) {
     console.log('fullfilled : ', result);
}
function rejected(err) {
     console.log('rejected : ', err);
}
new Promise(task1).then(fullfilled, rejected);
```

I just started node.js and was studying about promise module(?).
It could be a very basic question but I couldn't found out where the fulfilled and rejected method gets the parameter's value.

Comment: *where the fullfilled and rejected method gets the parameter's value* - what does that mean? Could you please clarify what you want to know?

Comment: I mean that fullfilled and rejected method gets the parameter result and err each.

Comment: you pass it here reject('Error msg');

Comment: You've misspelled "fulfill", by the way

Comment: Does it mean that when the code come to an action the parameter "err" gets the value from "reject('Error msg');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

```
p.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected]);

p.then(function(value) {
  // fulfillment
}, function(reason) {
  // rejection
});
```

onFulfilled
A Function called if the Promise is fulfilled. This function has one argument, the fulfillment value.
onRejected Optional
A Function called if the Promise is rejected. This function has one argument, the rejection reason.

```
let p = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(condition){
            // this arg would be caught in onFulfilled
            resolve(arg);
        }
        else{
            // this arg would be caught in onRejected
            reject(arg2);
        }
    })
}
```

take a look at p for clarity

Comment: oh!! I understood Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To add to @marvel308's answer, whatever you call `resolve()` with is available in the `then` clause and whatever you call the `reject()` with is available in the `catch` clause.

Consider:

```
function makePromise(condition) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    condition 
    ? resolve('2 + 2 = 4') 
    : reject('No, wait. Maybe it is 5.')
  })
}
```

Now, if we call this function with the `resolve` case:

```
makePromise(true)
.then(x => console.log(x)) // 2 + 2 = 4
.catch(x => console.log(x))
```

And with the `reject` case:

```
makePromise(false)
.then(x => console.log(x)) 
.catch(x => console.log(x)) // No, wait. Maybe it is 5.
```